# How to ask for Sudoku game input with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, input, sudoku

I wanted to create a sudoku solver with Tkinter. I want the user to be able to fill in some random numbers and my program should give a solution.

The first problem I ran into is that I need input from the user. I tried doing it by creating an Entry for every row and column combination but this doesn't work. It just gives me some weird looking columns separated from eachother.

How should I ask the user for numbers so that in all boxes a number can be filled in?

```
 from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title('Sudoku Solver')
root.geometry('460x550')

mylabel = Label(root, text='Fill in the numbers and click solve').grid(row=0, column=0,
                                                                                                    columnspan=10)

# Create the grid
def beg():
    cells = {}
    for row in range(1, 10):
        for column in range(1, 10):
            if ((row in (1,2,3,7,8,9) and column in (4,5,6)) or (row in (4,5,6) and column in (1,2,3,7,8,9))):
                kleur='green'
            else:
                kleur='orange'
            cell = Frame(root, bg='white', highlightbackground=kleur,
                         highlightcolor=kleur, highlightthickness=2,
                         width=50, height=50,  padx=3,  pady=3, background='black')
            cell.grid(row=row, column=column)
            cells[(row, column)] = cell
            for roww, columnn in cells:
                e = Entry(cells[roww, columnn])
                e.pack()


beg()

# Create the functions for buttons
def clear():
    return


def solve():
    return


# Create the buttons
clearer = Button(root, text='Clear', command=clear)
solver = Button(root, text='Solve', command=solve)

# Locate the buttons
clearer.grid(row=11, column=3, pady=30)
solver.grid(row=11, column=7, pady=30)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: First thing coming to mind is that you don't need frames. You can give the entries a color as well. Creating nine rows with pack(side=tk.TOP) and fill them with entries with pack(side=tk.LEFT) might work just as well. No one knows that you don't have a grid ;)

Comment: @PythonAmateur742 Thanks for your comment! Could you maybe write out that code in an answer please as I don't really know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you created an extra loop that wasn't needed, I took one out and now it looks fine, except for the entry width. 
I'm not certain if I got the rows and the columns mixed up though. But its a square, so it should work either way:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title('Sudoku Solver')
root.geometry('460x550')

mylabel = Label(root, text='Fill in the numbers and click solve').grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=10)

# Create the grid
def beg():
    cells = {}
    for row in range(1, 10):
        for column in range(1, 10):
            if ((row in (1,2,3,7,8,9) and column in (4,5,6)) or (row in (4,5,6) and column in (1,2,3,7,8,9))):
                kleur='green'
            else:
                kleur='orange'
            cell = Frame(root, bg='white', highlightbackground=kleur,
                         highlightcolor=kleur, highlightthickness=2,
                         width=50, height=50,  padx=3,  pady=3, background='black')
            cell.grid(row=row, column=column)
            cells[(row, column)] = cell
            # for roww, columnn in cells:
            e = Entry(cells[row, column])
            e.pack()



beg()

# Create the functions for buttons
def clear():
    return


def solve():
    return


# Create the buttons
clearer = Button(root, text='Clear', command=clear)
solver = Button(root, text='Solve', command=solve)

# Locate the buttons
clearer.grid(row=11, column=3, pady=30)
solver.grid(row=11, column=7, pady=30)


root.mainloop()
```

A little bit of extra explaining:
The combination of the first two loops (81 times) called this loop 81 times as well:

```
for roww, columnn in cells:
    e = Entry(cells[roww, columnn])
    e.pack()
```

Filling all 81 frames with 81 entry fields. That's what makes it look crazy.

Comment: Ahh yes I see what went wrong there now haha ;') Thanks!

Comment: The columns, however, are still kinda far away from each other. You happen to know what I should change so there is no space between them anymore?

Comment: I think changing the entry width. Try this ```e = Entry(cells[row, column], width=4)```